# What are the choices you can make to stay alive in One Chance?

Tags: one-chance

In the game [One Chance](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/555181) at Newgrounds, you're given a single chance to play through the game**. In mine, I didn't make it through alive because of a likely dumb decision at the start.

I assume there is at least one path that will allow you to live. If so, what is it? Are there other paths and choices that you can make that will allow you to make it through alive? If there are multiple paths, will any allow you to survive with other people?

** Yes, there are ways to go back and play through it again, just curious if others had tried it and if they found the one chance in their playthrough.

Comment: Just a note:  I followed the `One Chance` link in this post while using IE InPrivate Browsing, and got a popup that Avast! shut down as having a Trojan.

Comment: @Iszi are you sure this wasn't coincidental? newgrounds is a respected, high-quality site for hosting flash games and animations, and has been so for many years. I could personally take their word over Avast :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to discover the cure.

To discover it, you...

> ...just go to work every day that you can. Don't take Molly to park, don't stay home, don't celebrate, just work.

As far as I know, there's only one path, and the people that survive will be...

> ...just you and Molly as far as it shows. Although I guess that more could too that it doesn't show.

btw, you don't have to clear your cache to replay. I think that you can just use Private Browsing in Firefox, Incognito for Chrome, InPrivate in IE(ick), or a private tab/window in Opera. I only tested this with Firefox's, but I there tested it a lot. :P I got like every ending possible.

Comment: I tried looking through flash cookies to no avail. Don't tell me it's cookied normally...

Comment: I played it in normal mode at first, and just used private browsing the second, third, forth, and fifth play-throughs.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the comments here - http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2010/12/07/last-night-one-chance/ - there's a few scenarios that don't involve everyone dying...my play-through wasn't one of them, but there seems to be something useful about taking Molly to the park on the second to last day.

Comment: Thanks. Guess it's time to clear my cache and try some out.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is just work 24/7. And when its locked go to the roof where the people are, unless the man has the key to the lab. On the last day (if you worked every day) you'll see a box with a check mark on it while you're working. Then you take Molly to the park. You just do it automatically. (She's not dead in this ending, by the way)