# How can I prevent the untimely demise of John's wife?

Tags: one-chance

So far the only "happy" end I found was the one where [John and Molly are cured and sit in the park](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12489/88). Unfortunately, that involves

> having to go to work on every occasion, which results in

John's wife comitting suicide.

The only path that did not let John find his wife dead

> cheating on her so she leaves for her mother with Molly

is not very satisfying. Is there happier ending for all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few videos on [this page](http://blog.mad4flash.com/2010/12/one-chance-walkthrough-guide-review-and-discussion/) that go over the various endings.  Although it's possible there's a perfect ending where everything is fine, I highly doubt it.

The entire game is a meditation on making tough choices - you can put aside your own happiness and needs in order to save the planet, or you can spend a few more hours with your family, thereby sacrificing everyone's future.

The game wants to put you in a terrible situation and make you think about how you'd choose.  Feeling the effects of those choices is central to the experience.  Having an ending where everything works out fine for everyone is kind of counter to the message the game is trying to send, so I find it highly unlikely that one exists.

Comment: I hex-edited the savegame of finished games in the one byte that seems to determine which ending is shown, and none of them was fully happy... So unless the other bytes (too many to brute check all of them) encode a different ending, there is no "everyone lived happily ever after"